# How to remotely access a database on the Raspberry Pi?

Tags: database

I installed PhpPgAdmin on the Pi and want to access its database from my laptop.

If I type on my laptop's browser `http://192.168.1.97/phppgadmin`, `192.168.1.97` being the inet adress of my Pi, I get a message from Apache saying

> You don't have permission to access `/phppgadmin` on this server.

How can I change that permission?

Comment: You could try using Filezilla or WinSCP. I've used Filezilla to remotely access files through SFTP with no issues.

Comment: Solved it myself. Run the command: sudo nano /etc/apache2/phppgadmin.conf and comment the line "Require local" it will allow you to access from http://<Rpi-inet-adress>/phpphadmin

Comment: @C-dizzle: sftp isn't helpful if you want to access a database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved it myself. Run the command: `sudo nano /etc/apache2/phppgadmin.conf`and comment the line "Require local" it will allow you to access from 
http://[Rpi-inet-adress]/phpphadmin

Answer (score 0):

You can permit all networks access;

```
sed -i .bak 's/^(Require local)/#$1/' /etc/apache2/phppgadmin.conf
```

or a more secure option is to use a SOCS 5 proxy so your browser is considered local;

```
ssh -fND 127.0.0.1:8080 pi@192.168.1.97 2>/dev/null >&1
```